# Mongodb Stitch realtime watch

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-stitch

What I intend to achieve is some sort of "live query" functionality.
So far I've tried using the "watch" method. According to the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/mongodb/watch/):

> You can open a stream of changes that match a filter by calling
>   collection.watch(delegate:) with a $match expression as the argument.
>   Whenever the watched collection changes and the ChangeEvent matches
>   the provided $match expression, the stream’s event handler fires with
>   the ChangeEvent object as its only argument

Passing the doc ids as an array works perfectly, but passing a query doesn't work:

```
this.stitch.db.collection<Queue>('queues')
                        .watch({
                          hospitalId: this.activehospitalid
                         }));
```

I've also tried this:

```
this.stitch.db.collection<Queue>('queues')
                        .watch({
                           $match: {
                              hospitalId: this.activehospitalid
                              }
                            },
                          ));
```

Which throws an error on the console "StitchServiceError: mongodb watch: filter is invalid (unknown top level operator: $match)". The intention is watch all documents where the field "hospitalId" matches the provided value, or to effectively pass a query filter to the `watch()` method.

Comment: what language/sdk are you using?

Comment: this is in typescript ono an angular app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long search I found that it's possible to filter, but the query needs to be formatted differently

```
this.stitch.db.collection<Queue>('queues')
                        .watch({
                           $or: [
                                 {
                                   "fullDocument.hospitalId": this.activehospitalid
                                 }
                                ]
                            },
                          ));
```

For anyone else who might need this, please note the important **fullDocument** part of the query. I havent found much documentation relating to this, but I hope it helps